# How far an Internship is helpful for Graduate School Admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student currently enrolled in a 3 year Bachelor of Science Mathematics Course. I am a non-US citizen and student.

I have an ambition to study in Ivy Leagues and other prestigious universities in my Master's Course in Mathematics at the  USA. However, due to my financial constratints, I will be unable to do it, unless a financial aid is provided which will include my tuition fees, boarding cost  and  medical insurance.

I have heard a lot that how doing a lot of research and internships boosts one's profile. But being a "noob", in all these stuffs, I don't know where to start. Is it mandatory to do these stuffs to be in the competition or just focussing on college courses suffiecient for the purpose ?

My friends already set up a LinkedIn account and suggests me to do the same. Unfortunately/Fortunately, I created a disposable account in LinkedIn, and then I got confused and had no idea how to "use it" and was forced to delete it.

I live in India and I come from a middle-class family. Our annual family income is, $487.34(approx). This is all I can say about my financial condition. So, without a scholarship it is next to impossible to fulfil my dream.

I have heard, that obtaining scholarships are really very competitive. So, will internships help me in here as well?

Seniors have adviced me to do some projects under Professors, or internships is somewhat helpful in here and honestly it depends upon the university I am applying to.

The problem is, I dont know where to begin! Any suggestion regarding these will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Study at the masters level is seldom funded in US. Doctoral level study is usually funded through a Teaching Assistantship. You might look into that. Also, the Ivys are very selective.

Comment: @Buffy Oh, so do you suggest going to the US for a phd?

Comment: If you qualify, then it is a better option. You don't need a masters to begin doctoral study here. But look much more broadly at research (R1) universities. See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/176909/75368